# \cite{label} never display number

Tags: biblatex

Desperate and get stuck with a super easy question:

This is my `bibtest.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\input{config/config.tex}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bib/main.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black,urlcolor=blue}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\clearpage

As indicated in the famous thesis of Church-Turing Thesis\cite{turing1936computable}, 

and Minsky's Perceptron article\cite{minsky2017perceptrons}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This is the `main.bib`:

```
@article{turing1936computable,
  title={On computable numbers, with an application to the Entscheidungsproblem},
  author={Turing, Alan Mathison},
  journal={J. of Math},
  volume={58},
  number={345-363},
  pages={5},
  year={1936}
}
@book{minsky2017perceptrons,
  title={Perceptrons: An introduction to computational geometry},
  author={Minsky, Marvin and Papert, Seymour A},
  year={2017},
  publisher={MIT press}
}
```

Using MikTeX 2.9, the result is:

> As indicated in the famous thesis of Church-Turing
>   Thesis[**turing1936computable**], and Minsky's Perceptron
>   article[**minsky2017perceptrons**]

---

The desired "[1]"  and "[2]" did not appear, and no Reference is printed.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you run biber?

Comment: I did, both miktext and command line:  pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex

Comment: **bibtex** is not **biber**

Comment: I guees I am an idiot....got mixed up

Comment: But I did  \usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}

Comment: Sure you are telling biblatex that you will use biber later. Then you should really do it, and not use bibtex instead.

Comment: how to use biber?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: well on the command line you simply have to use `biber bibtest`. To setup your editor see here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations

Comment: it worked,  thanks a lot !!!  One last question, must I use command line? Can miktext do the job?

Comment: @Chia-ChenChan - MikTeX, BibTeX, and biber are all separate standalone programs. The latter two serve to create a formatted bibliography; the former compiles the full LaTeX document, including the creation of the citation call-outs. MikTeX will never, ever replace either BibTeX or biber.

Comment: You don't have to use the command line to compile your document with Biber. If you are using an editor, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help with setting it up for Biber.